# Why does Appium push the apk?

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm currently working on an automation project for setting up tablets. I am very familiar with Selenium and Java. To keep this question simple, which one of these lines is pushing the apk? What if I want to push multiple apks?

```
public class AppiumTest {

private static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

@BeforeTest
public void firstatest() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.4.0");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "0123456789ABCDEF");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/User/Documents/Appium/1.apk"); // ########
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "FILL-IN-INFORMATION"); // ########
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "FILL-IN-INFORMATION"); // ########
URL serveraddress = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(serveraddress, capabilities);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(serveraddress, capabilities);
```

above line will create a new session and it will check app is installed or not. If not it will install and open the app.

You can not push multiple apks when you start a new session, but later you can install apks by calling `driver.installApp(apkPath);` method.

Comment: If I get rid of this line `AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(serveraddress, capabilities);` aswell as the `appPackage` and `appActivity` capabiities, will my test still run? I'm primarily using Appium as a tool to batch prepare tablets (install apks and change settings automatically).

Comment: appPackage and appActivity capabiities are not required with latest appium . Without AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(serveraddress, capabilities); line apk wont get installed.

Comment: If your aim is to install multiple apks then you can use adb command to install multiple apks.

Answer (score 1):

For Ques1) which one of these lines is pushing the apk?

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/User/Documents/Appium/1.apk");
```

If you comment out the above line. Appium will not install the app when you initialise the driver. It will only search for the appPackage and reset the app.

```
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(serveraddress, capabilities);
```

For Ques2) What if I want to push multiple apks?

I am not sure you can do it with using capabilities. One way would be to install test app with capability and the other apps by writing a utility which installs app via adb.

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ADB_PATH,"shell","pm install /path to apk on the test phone/"+apkName});
```

It would be interesting to see if it can be done via capabilities or driver element though. Would appreciate if the community suggests something.